# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector2?' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

This might seem a noob question to ask but I am using gamespark with unity. 
I am sending vector2 in the pack like this:

```
data.SetVector2(1, new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
```

and I get it from the packet like:

```
Vector2 a = _packet.Data.GetVector2 (1);
```

But I am getting the following error:
Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Vector2? to UnityEngine.Vector2.

Comment: Random question: `new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)` why are you passing 3 parameters to a Vector2 which can only store 2 values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The '?' means it is a "nullable" type.  To convert to a Vector2, do

```
Vector2 a = _packet.Data.GetVector2(1).Value;
```

Here is a link on nullable types from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Nullable types also have the option to check if the value is null or not with the `HasValue` property.  If you aren't certain that `GetVector2` actually returns a valid value, you should check `HasValue` and respond appropriately.

Comment: I was going to. It said I had to wait atleast 10minutes for it... so yeah. Thanks again